# Invalid private key file in c# with ppk file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sftp, private-key

I am writing a test case where i am trying to connect to SFTP using passphrase and Private key file
but getting above exception

here is my code what i have tried

```
public void ConnectToSFTPTest()
{
        var filename = @"C:\PvtKey.ppk";
        var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(filename, "passphrase"); --here i am getting exception
        var keyFiles = new[] { pk };

        var client =  new SftpClient("hostname", 22, "username", keyFiles);
        client.Connect();
        if(client.IsConnected)
        {
           client.Disconnect();
        }
        Assert.True(true);
}
```

Can anybody help me to get it working my file is ppk

Answer (score -1):

This is because a PPK (putty private key) is a none standard format that is used by PuTTY and putty based applications, the library you're using requires an OpenSSH formatted key.

So you need to use PuTTYgen then load the PPK file and then export the file in OpenSSH format (Conversions > Export OpenSSH Key) also save the public key file this will give a converted file which one can use to fetch the data

Comment: While this is technically correct, you might want to explain why, E.G PPK are a putty formated version of the key and needs to be converted to an OpenSSH formatted key.

Comment: Yes, as my answer to the duplicate question says. Please do not post duplicate answers.

Comment: Instead, please consider upvoting the posts that have helped you.